# PostgreSQLでpg_restoreエラー

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

PostgreSQLにdumpファイルをインポートしようとしてpg_restoreを利用したら、下記のエラーが出力されました。

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2864; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  讖溯・諡｡蠑ｵplpgsql縺ｮ謇譛芽・〒縺ｪ縺代ｌ縺ｰ縺ｪ繧翫∪縺帙ｓ
   Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';



pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 196; 1259 28241 TABLE active_admin_comments flicfit
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  繝ｭ繝ｼ繝ｫ"flicfit"縺ｯ蟄伜惠縺励∪縺帙ｓ
   Command was: ALTER TABLE public.active_admin_comments OWNER TO flicfit;
```

文字化けして恐縮ですが、英数字から何かわかるものはないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Windows環境が手元にないので確認できませんが、[Windowsコマンドプロンプト　文字コード設定](https://qiita.com/user0/items/a9116acc7bd7b70ecfb0)という記事にコマンドプロンプトで`chcp 65001`を実行するとコマンドプロンプトの文字コードを`UTF-8`にできるようです。文字コードを`UTF-8`に変えてから再度`pg_restore`すると文字化け部分を確認できるのではと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';

plpgsql拡張のコメントに関するクエリーが実行できなかったというエラーです。権限がないことでエラーが発生する場合が多いので、「管理者から実行する」でコマンドプロンプトを起動して、`pg_restore`の接続ユーザーを`postgres`にすれば発生しなくなる場合が多いと思いますが、無視をしても問題がないケースも多いと思います。詳しいことは英語版に質問 [PostgreSQL 9.1 pg_restore error regarding PLPGSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169203) があるのでみてください。

> Command was: ALTER TABLE public.active_admin_comments OWNER TO flicfit;

テーブル`public.active_admin_comments`の所有者を`flicfit`に変更できなかったというエラーです。原因として最も考えられるのは、`flicfit`というユーザーが作成できていないというケースです。`pg_dump`では、ユーザー(ロール)のバックアップはできないので、先に`pg_dumpall`を`--roles-only`オプションをつけてバックアップしてリストアしておきます。一人だけであればSQLコマンドを叩いた方が早いと思います。

Comment: みなさんありがとうございます。